# Packing Linked Blend Files with textures?

Tags: linked-data, packed-data

I'm struggling to get a file packed so that I can set up a render farm at my work, the problem I'm having is that the textures are not packing from the Linked files, everything else is working fine from Particle Systems to Actions to rigs everything except the textures.

I found this video by AgenZasBrothers youtube channel

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8I81FohzSjo&t=366s

It outlines the process from ensuring you pack the individual library blends first, so I've done that and those files are indeed packed, the file size increases and if I go to unpack them there are files to unpack.  I then go into the main file and hit space bar select 'Pack Blender Libraries' I then pack the main file again and save as a new file but it still has no textures.

I got nothing, please help.

Tom